# SQL Server joining trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

### Scenario:

I am trying to build a query which has a start and end date, And the result of this query gives me the days in between and the day name. I then want to `JOIN` to another table which has expected pay dates and amounts. The `JOINED` table may have more days outside the range of the start and end date, which I want to exclude.

### Progress:

I sort-of have what I want, but not in the correct output, I have created the following thus far:

```
DECLARE 
@startDate DATETIME,
@endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-21'
SET @endDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -0, GETDATE())))+'-20'
;WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date,DATENAME(Dw,@startdate) As DayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date]),DATENAME(Dw,DATEADD(d,1,[Date])) as DayName
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Date, 106), 2) + '-' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Date, 10), 2) Date,DayName, SUM(ExpectedAmount), ExpectedDate FROM dates
FULL JOIN Commissions.dbo.ThreeMonthPayment on CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Date) = Commissions.dbo.ThreeMonthPayment.ExpectedDate
GROUP BY Date, DayName, ExpectedDate
Order by ExpectedDate
```

Which results in this table (Sorry so long):

```
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+
| Date  |  DayName  | (No column name) | ExpectedDate |
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | NULL         |
| 21-03 | Friday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 22-03 | Saturday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 23-03 | Sunday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 24-03 | Monday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 25-03 | Tuesday   | NULL             | NULL         |
| 26-03 | Wednesday | NULL             | NULL         |
| 27-03 | Thursday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 28-03 | Friday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 29-03 | Saturday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 30-03 | Sunday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 31-03 | Monday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 01-04 | Tuesday   | NULL             | NULL         |
| 02-04 | Wednesday | NULL             | NULL         |
| 03-04 | Thursday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 04-04 | Friday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 05-04 | Saturday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 06-04 | Sunday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 07-04 | Monday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 08-04 | Tuesday   | NULL             | NULL         |
| 09-04 | Wednesday | NULL             | NULL         |
| 10-04 | Thursday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 11-04 | Friday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 12-04 | Saturday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 13-04 | Sunday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 14-04 | Monday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 15-04 | Tuesday   | NULL             | NULL         |
| 16-04 | Wednesday | NULL             | NULL         |
| 17-04 | Thursday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 18-04 | Friday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| 19-04 | Saturday  | NULL             | NULL         |
| 20-04 | Sunday    | NULL             | NULL         |
| NULL  | NULL      | 89466            | 01-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 86058            | 01-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 23356            | 01-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 1858             | 01-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 13597            | 02-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 55587            | 02-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 7857             | 02-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 1377             | 02-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 6947             | 03-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 49626            | 03-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 03-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 03-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 6054             | 04-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 31639            | 04-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 04-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 04-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 26421            | 05-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 28154            | 05-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 15036            | 05-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 634              | 05-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 05-07        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 20832            | 06-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 06-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 06-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 06-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 5406             | 07-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 12864            | 07-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 4257             | 07-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 537              | 07-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 08-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 363              | 08-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 426              | 08-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 08-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 09-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 23240            | 09-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 09-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 09-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 12670            | 10-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 6790             | 10-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 10-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 10-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 2914             | 11-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 19053            | 11-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 11-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 11-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 6402             | 12-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 12-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 12-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 12-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 4166             | 13-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 13-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 13-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 13-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 50534            | 14-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 23854            | 14-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 15435            | 14-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 4003             | 14-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 475330           | 15-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 451014           | 15-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 103210           | 15-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 19947            | 15-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 12084            | 16-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 22203            | 16-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 517              | 16-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 16-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 31423            | 17-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 32150            | 17-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 17-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 17-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 33402            | 18-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 900              | 18-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 289              | 18-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 18-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 33929            | 19-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 6942             | 19-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 19-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 19-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 161806           | 20-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 141319           | 20-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 26659            | 20-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 4695             | 20-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 21074            | 21-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 15579            | 21-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 2693             | 21-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 21-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 28401            | 22-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 46258            | 22-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 11409            | 22-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 1672             | 22-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 76562            | 23-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 66804            | 23-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 32853            | 23-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 3168             | 23-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 47008            | 24-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 35888            | 24-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 4528             | 24-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 459              | 24-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 1108747          | 25-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 543351           | 25-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 152852           | 25-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 15712            | 25-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 343379           | 26-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 117657           | 26-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 41793            | 26-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 5645             | 26-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 27-02        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 401110           | 27-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 87571            | 27-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 39192            | 27-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 2801             | 27-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 313274           | 28-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 92607            | 28-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 21901            | 28-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 1852             | 28-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 77999            | 29-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 27693            | 29-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 3341             | 29-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | 29-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 229556           | 30-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 261036           | 30-04        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 9109             | 30-05        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 545              | 30-06        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 460871           | 31-03        |
| NULL  | NULL      | 28710            | 31-05        |
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+
```

Out of the above results, I am trying to match the `ExpectedDate` to the `date` column , so instead of seeing the above results, I would have something that looks like this: (to keep it short, i haven't created all of the days I receive from my start and end date)

```
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+
| Date  |  DayName  | (No column name) | ExpectedDate |
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+
| NULL  | NULL      | 0                | NULL         |
| 21-03 | Friday    | 21074            | 21-03        |
| 22-03 | Saturday  | 28401            | 22-03        |
| 23-03 | Sunday    | 76562            | 23-03        |
| 24-03 | Monday    | 47008            | 24-03        |
+-------+-----------+------------------+--------------+
```

But you can see above that the `expectedDate` and `date` column are grouped / joined nicely together. And the `expectedDates` that are not in the `date` range are not displayed.

I have been struggling with this the entire morning :( is this possible ??

Any help or links to threads that I may have missed would be great!

`I am using SQL SERVER 2008`

---

Thanks so much.

Comment: you should create a sql fiddle of this so that people can play around with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the `full join` includes everything. from both tables. if you only want the dates from the `dates` cte, use left join.

secondly, the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Date) = Commissions.dbo.ThreeMonthPayment.ExpectedDate` seems to not work. are you sure you need to convert?

i suggest you try this:

```
DECLARE 
@startDate DATETIME,
@endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-21'
SET @endDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -0, GETDATE())))+'-20'
;WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date,DATENAME(Dw,@startdate) As DayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date]),DATENAME(Dw,DATEADD(d,1,[Date])) as DayName
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Date, 106), 2) + '-' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Date, 10), 2) Date
     , DayName, SUM(ExpectedAmount), ExpectedDate 
  FROM dates
  LEFT JOIN Commissions.dbo.ThreeMonthPayment 
    on Date = Commissions.dbo.ThreeMonthPayment.ExpectedDate
 GROUP BY 
       Date
     , DayName
     , ExpectedDate
 Order by 
       ExpectedDate
```